Understanding why single-particle QM is not enough or accurate in relativistic quantum mechanics
In a book that I am reading ("QFT for the gifted amateur") it is said that, single-particle quantum
mechanics fails when faced with special relativity. An example, which I will present below is used to prove this. The example, ignoring for a moment the mathematics involved, is straightforward. But I fail to see how, what was calculated and showed, implies that there is a problem with single-particle QM, and somehow switching to fields would solve the problem, described below.
We ask the question:

"what is the amplitude for a particle to travel outside its forward light-cone?"

Or in other words:

"what is the amplitude for a particle
at the origin in spacetime ($x = 0, t = 0$) to travel to position $x$ at time $t$ which would require it to travel faster than light?"

Faster than light means $|x|>t$ and the interval $(x − 0, t − 0)$ is space-like If the amplitude is nonzero then there will be a nonzero probability for a particle to be found outside its forward light-cone. This is not physically possible. So if we are able to get a non-zero result then we somehow have proven that single-particle QM is not relevant anymore in RQM (relativistic quantum mechanics.)
The example considers:
$\mathcal{A}=\langle \vec x|e^{-iHt}|x=0\rangle$ for the space-like interval. First thing I'd want to ask is what is the logic behind this expression and how does one come about it? In the book this was just considered but wasn't motivated or argued. It's as if it fell from the sky.
In the book the expression is calculated, it involves complex analysis concepts such as branch cuts and branch points. And the result is a non-zero value.
Then, because we get a non-zero probability of the particle traveling faster than light, we say that the single-particle qm is not valid in QM anymore.
While I, obviously, understand the fact that non-zero probability of something unphysical taking place makes no sense, I don't understand how single-particle qm is the cause of this and HOW the consideration of fields would fix this problem.

Well, the "logic" behind the expression is simply QM. Other than that I'd agree that the example presented as such does not make any claim about the potential success of QFT. It only shows that a very "naive" approach does not work.

In the passage quoted from your book it is argued that the naive attempt constructing a relativistic quantum theory by simply replacing the nonrelativistic Hamiltonian $H_{\rm nr}=\vec{p}^2/2m$ by the relativistic expression $H=c(\vec{p}^2+m^2c^2)^{1/2}$ within the framework of kindergarten one-particle quantum mechanics is doomed to fail as it turns out to violate the requirement of causality. In such a context, one assumes the existence of one-particle "states" $|\vec{x}\rangle$ of a particle exactly localized at the point $\vec{x}$. The amplitude to find the particle at point $\vec{x}$ at time $t>0$ if it was initially (time $t=0$) localized at point $\vec{y}$ would then be given by the time-evolution kernel
$$
\langle \vec{x} |e^{-iHt/\hbar} |\vec{y}\rangle \tag{1} \label{1}
$$
discussed in your book. The fact that \eqref{1} does not vanish for space-like space-time intervals $$c^2 t^2- (\vec{x}-\vec{y})^2 <0 \tag{2} \label{2}$$ has disastrous consequences. Suppose the state of your particle is initially described by the wavefunction $\psi(t=0, \vec{x})=\langle \vec{x} |\psi(t=0)\rangle$ confined to some (small) space region. According to the Schrödinger equation, its wavefunction at $t>0$ is given by
$$
\psi(t, \vec{x}) = \int \! d^3y \, \langle \vec{x} |e^{-iHt/\hbar} |\vec{y} \rangle\underbrace{ \langle \vec{y} | \psi(t=0) \rangle}_{\psi(t=0, \vec{y})}. \tag{3} \label{3}
$$
Preparing a large number of particles in the same initial state (described by $ | \psi(t=0)\rangle$), there will be some fraction of particles propagating faster than the speed of light $c$ as
a consequence of the non-vanishing contribution of \eqref{1} for space-like intervals. As you can see from the explicit form of the propagation kernel in your book, this effect becomes more pronounced if the (linear) size of the space region occupied by the particle in the initial state gets closer  to its Compton length $\lambda_{\rm C} =\hbar/m c$. Phrased differently, the notion of a one-particle position-space wave function $\psi(\vec{x}) = \langle \vec{x} | \psi \rangle$ does not make sense anymore in the relativistic regime.
We see that this naive "theory" is critically ill, being clearly in conflict with the requirements of (special) relativity and causality. What is the physical reason for its failure? Once you operate with a position eigenstate $|\vec{x} \rangle$ of a single particle, you are tacitely assuming that this particle can (at least in principle) be confined to an arbitrarily small region of space, at the same time still remaining a single particle. But this is not that what happens in nature. If you try to confine a particle to smaller and smaller regions of space, its typical momentum will increase, eventually leaving the nonrelativistic domain.   As a consequence, the associated energy of the system gets large enough ($E >\!> mc^2$) to produce more particles  and the framework of a one-particle description breaks down.
Thus, a quantum theory applicable at relativistic energies is necessarily a multi-particle theory, abandoning at the same time conservation of particle number. It turns out that the appropriate multi-particle theory is nothing else than relativistic quantum field theory, but this is a different story...
